# can I use the command "sudo apt-get install something" in a USB pen drive plugged to my PC?

Tags: partitioning, usb, 15.04, sudo, storage

I want to install a programm in my USB pen drive.

I know there is enough storage in my PC to install what I need but I want to install that thing in my USB drive, just to keep it not in my primary hdd.
Is this thing possible? Can I do that? Does a particular command exist to do such a thing?

Thank for the help

Comment: apt-get will not do this for you. You would have to compile from source code and specify the location. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo , prefix=/path/to/your/usb

Comment: You cannot do it by `apt` as Mr. bodhi.zazen said. Can we know what software you want to install into your USB pendrive?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that, if the partitions of the USB drive aren't mounted at the right places or without using symbolic links.

And believe me, you do not want to do that!